# how can python parse utf8 string

Tags: python, utf8-decode

Now I get some info via http request. But I find the String can not be parsed to the correct charset. This is my code:

```
req = urllib2.Request(URL, urllib.urlencode({"token": token}))
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
result = resp.read()
print result  #\u8c22\u777f
print repr(result ) #'\\u8c22\\u777f'
```

The correct string should be `\u8c22\u777f`, but the `\u` is escaped to `\\u`. What shall I do?

Comment: Are you sure that output is fully accurate, e.g. there are no double quotes?

Comment: the output is coped from the console. I am sure about it. You can test it like result = '\\u8c22\\u777f'    print result